# MariaDB CONCAT / GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mariadb, concatenation, blob

I have a table where I've imported binary data into a 'LONGBLOB' field each record.  The original binary file is 1260,476,676 bytes or 1.17GB, I have split this file into 5 records and now I have 5 records 4 of which contain 268,435,456 and the last one contains 186,734,852

I now want to write a query that rejoins these into a single LONGBLOB, can this be done with a query or would it be easier to query all 5 and join in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the MariaDB documentation for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/), you should be able to simply `GROUP_CONCAT` the records together.

> If group_concat_max_len <= 512, the return type is VARBINARY or
> VARCHAR; otherwise, the return type is BLOB or TEXT. The choice
> between binary or non-binary types depends from the input.

Note that in order for you to be able to concatenate a large result using `GROUP_CONCAT`, the value of [`group_concat_max_len`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#group_concat_max_len) must be increased from the default value.

> The maximum returned length in bytes is determined by the
> group_concat_max_len server system variable, which defaults to 1M (>=
> MariaDB 10.2.4) or 1K (<= MariaDB 10.2.3).